# aligning equations with a tag

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, align

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{marginnote} 
\begin{document}
$$ KP = e^{-\lambda} \Big( \frac {\nu'}{r} +\frac {1}{r}\Big) -\frac {1}{r^2}$$
    \begin {gather}
    \Rightarrow \frac {dP}{dr} = - \frac { P+\rho (P) c^2}{r(r-2u)} \Big[ \frac {K}{2} P r^3 +u \Big] \tag {**}
    \end {gather}
\end {document}
```

How do I align them ?

Comment: Please read http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to on the `$$...$$` topic

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Put both of them in an `align` environment and use ampersands `&` to mark positions.

Comment: Aligning equations is pretty basic. Please have a look at mathmode.pdf which you can [find on CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode). Section 25 has all the information you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  KP &= e^{-\lambda} \Big( \frac {\nu'}{r} +\frac {1}{r}\Big) -\frac {1}{r^2} \\[2ex]
 \Rightarrow \frac {dP}{dr} &= - \frac { P+\rho (P) c^2}{r(r-2u)} \Big[ \frac {K}{2} P r^3 +u \Big] \tag {**}
\end {align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]